# how to get list of documents where their id given from another collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections

**collections pdm**:

[image]

I want to make a stream reads favorite providers for user

```
 Stream<List<FavoriteProvider>> get favoriteProviders{
    return favoriteProviderCollection.where('userID', isEqualTo: this.uid).snapshots()
      .map(_favoriteproviderListfromsnapshot);
  }

  List<FavoriteProvider> _favoriteproviderListfromsnapshot (QuerySnapshot snapshot){
     return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
      var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return FavoriteProvider(
        providerID: data['providerID'],
        userID: data['userID']
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

but how to complete?

I tried this but it seems not good

```
final favoriteProviders = Provider.of<List<FavoriteProvider>>(context);
      return new StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('providers').doc(favoriteProviders).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container();
          }
          List<ServineraProvider> servineraProviders = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(...)
}
);
```

any one can help me

Comment: thery are 3 with the users collection but it is not important for the code

Comment: What you are trying to do is called a "join" in database terminology.  Firestore does not support join queries between collections for performance and scalability reasons.  You will have to perform at least two separate queries (as you are now) in order to get what you want.

Comment: oki can u help me im new to firebase